# Does Heremaps support custom map URL similar to Bing Map?

Tags: here-api, bing-maps, heremaps

Am I able to construct a custom URL using Heremap? For example, with Bing Map, I'm able to contruct a custom URL with various parameters and set the link to something like this for the user to click on:

```
https://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?rtp=adr.One%20Microsoft%20Way,%20Redmond,%20WA%2098052~pos.45.23423_-122.1232_MyPlace&rtop=0~1~0
```

This is the instructions for Bing Map to do this, but I can't find something similar for Heremap:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/create-a-custom-map-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see it documented anywhere, but I figured out a few ways to do this with the HEE We Go site.

To search by address or name, you can create a URL like: `https://wego.here.com/search/[query]`

For example: `https://wego.here.com/search/One%20Microsoft%20Way,%20Redmond,%20WA%2098052`

You can add `,[map style]` if you want to also set the map style. where the map style can be; `normal`, `satellite`, `terrain`, `traffic`, or `public_transport`.

For example; `https://wego.here.com/search/One%20Microsoft%20Way,%20Redmond,%20WA%2098052,satellite`

If you want to go straight to a coordinate, you can use the following format:
`https://wego.here.com/?map=[latitude],[longitude],[zoom],[map style]`

For example: `https://wego.here.com/?map=47.62114,-122.34654,18,satellite`